# Modify Existing Excel File using Apache POI Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

so I'm having an issue with modifying an excel file. I'm not sure if the way I wrote the directory was wrong when outputting the stream or what, but the data never gets modified. I don't receive any errors and no new file gets created on my desktop and the existing file stays the same. I know my data being modified is happening because my goal was to remove rows that had the same data from previous rows. I printed out my ArrayList and all the rows that were duplicated got deleted. Please help! Running on OX X by the way.

```
public class readInExcel {
static void readExcel() throws IOException
{

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "xls","xlsx");

    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new 
    File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());

    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {   
        File OGFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        String fileName = "user.home.Desktop";

        XSSFWorkbook wb;
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(OGFile)) {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            //Row row = rowIterator.next();
            XSSFRow currentRow;
            int a = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            int columnIndex = 18;
            for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex <= a; rowIndex++)
            {
                Row row = CellUtil.getRow(rowIndex, sheet);
                Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, columnIndex);

              data.contains(cell.getStringCellValue());
                  if(data.contains(cell.getStringCellValue()))
                    if(row != null)
                        sheet.removeRow(row);
                    else
                        data.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }

        try (FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new 
        File("user\\home\\Desktop\new.xlsx"))) {
            wb.write(outFile);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Fix the path in your `File` for the outputstream to something that's valid and appropriate on OSX?

Comment: I've tried user.home.Desktop.new.xlsx and still nothing :(

Comment: The try-with-resources-statement is not my friend. At least not in development process as it suppresses exceptions. Don't using try-with-resources-statement at least for the output to get appropriate exceptions from `wb.write(outFile)`.